# Creating a tableViewCell with a mapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm creating a tableViewCell with a mapView inside. however i can't seem to add a annotation based on a location in the viewController containing the tableView. i've started by in the cellForRowAtIndex by setting `cell.location = orgObject.coordinate` after that i've added following code to my custom cell. However `location` variable keep returning nil. i guess this is because `awakeForNib` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called? how do i solve this?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MKMapViewDelegate {

  var location: CLLocation?
  @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView?



  override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      // Initialization code



      //MapView
      mapView!.showsPointsOfInterest = true
      if let mapView = self.mapView
      {
          mapView.delegate = self
      }


      let orgLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location!.coordinate.latitude, location!.coordinate.longitude)

      let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
      dropPin.coordinate = orgLocation
      mapView!.addAnnotation(dropPin)

      self.mapView?.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(orgLocation, 500, 500), animated: true)


  }

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

      // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      // Initialisation code

      //MapView
      mapView!.showsPointsOfInterest = true
      if let mapView = self.mapView
      {
          mapView.delegate = self
      }
}
```

Call cell.showLocation(location) from cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func showLocation(location:CLLocation) {
      let orgLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location!.coordinate.latitude, location!.coordinate.longitude)

      let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
      dropPin.coordinate = orgLocation
      mapView!.addAnnotation(dropPin)
self.mapView?.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(orgLocation, 500, 500), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: mapView will be declared in cell class and it is setting in awakefromNib. so in showLocation method you can access self.mapView . Are you still facing issue? please provide details

Comment: naah was just passing the cell to the showLocation aswell

Comment: don't pass cell as parameter in showLocationMethod. you can access mapView in Cell class like self.mapView